# Get the column from an array

Tags: php

I'm a newbie, can someone help me?

I have an array

```
array(2) {
 ["Peter"]=>
  object(stdClass)#504 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "2226"
    ["name"]=>
     string(4) "Peter"
   }
 ["Sam"]=>
  object(stdClass)#505 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "2227"
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Sam"
   }
}
```

I want to get element from the column "id" then put into the sql for looping

```
$idcol = array()
foreach($info as $item){
$idcol[] = $item['id'];
}
```

But I don't know why I cannot get the id column.

For Looping,How to put the array element of $idcol into the sql? get_sql is a function

```
 for($i=0;$i<count($idcol);$i++){
 $rate = get_sql($idcol);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are not able to access the value form the array is that the details are stored as object, so you need to use **arrow operator '->'** to acces the values. So you can try the code as below :

```
$idcol = array()
foreach($info as $person_details)
{
    $id = $person_details->id;
    $person_name = $person_details->name;
    $idcol[] = $id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate through `$info` in `$item` you have object, not an array. 
So you need to call it `$item->id`

if `get_sql()` accept only one id you need to do something like

```
foreach ($idcol as $id){
    $rate = get_sql($id);
}
```

but it is always bad idea to query SQL inside the loop. Consider to change your SQL query to something like

```
SELECT * from `table` where `id` IN (1, 2, 3);
```

than you will retrieve all data at once.
But if you still want to call function you don't need two loops. Just do all stuff in one.

```
$idcol = array()
foreach($info as $item){
  $rate = get_sql($item->id);
}
```

but note, that rate will be rewritten in each iteration. So you need to collect data to array like `$rate[] = get_sql($item->id);` or process that data immediately like print it.

Comment: thankyou !!
can you solve me second question about the looping

Comment: to solve your second question i need to know what goes wrong now or any errors you get or what parameters that function expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$info` is the array mentioned at the beginning, each `$item` is an object, not an array. So you should try:

```
foreach($info as $item){
    $idcol[] = $item->id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to get the ids:

```
$idcol = array_map(function($item){return $item->id;},$info);
```

Then you can use a `foreach` loop to send the values to your function (though it would be best if you could make your function work with arrays to avoid multiple queries):

```
foreach($idcol as $id){
    $rate = get_sql($id);
}
```

The reason your current loop doesn't work is because you're sending the whole array and not using an index like `$idcol[i]`

Answer (score -1):

array_column — Return the values from a single column in the input array

Syntax
Description

```
array array_column ( array $array , mixed $column_key [, mixed $index_key = null ] )
```

array_column() returns the values from a single column of the array, identified by the column_key. Optionally, you may provide an index_key to index the values in the returned array by the values from the index_key column in the input array.

Example:

```
<?php
// Array representing a possible record set returned from a database
$records = array(
    array(
        'id' => 2135,
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3245,
        'first_name' => 'Sally',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5342,
        'first_name' => 'Jane',
        'last_name' => 'Jones',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5623,
        'first_name' => 'Peter',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    )
);

$first_names = array_column($records, 'first_name');
print_r($first_names);
?>
```

Get column of last names from recordset, indexed by the "id" column

```
<?php
// Using the $records array from Example #1
$last_names = array_column($records, 'last_name', 'id');
print_r($last_names);
?>
```

Comment: I dont know why i cannot get anything when using array_column

Comment: array_column can not be used because in isn't array.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $idcol = array()
 foreach($info as $item=>$val)
 {
    $idcol[] = $val['id'];
 }
```

Comment: `$val` is Object, not an array.